# Unable to programmatically render webform with CAPTCHA

Tags: 8, webforms, captcha

Our website has a custom route, with a controller rendering a custom Webform. This is required, as the form has some hidden fields to be pre-populated.

Now I would like to add the CAPTCHA module to the webform. When enabling the CAPTCHA for Drupal's default contact form and viewing it in incognito mode, it works nicely. The CAPTCHA shows up.

But when adding the CAPTCHA element to the custom form, it is not displayed at all.

[I've tried several ways to embed the form](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-cookbook/how-to-embed-a-webform), but none is working:

- Embed as a Webform entity (using `getSubmissionForm(..)`)
- Embed as a Webform entity (using `getViewBuilder('webform')`)
- Embed as a render array with the new element type webform

Would be glad to get any info on what's wrong here?

Comment: Are there any JS errors in console? Is the element rendered on the page, but not visible (i.e. in the HTML source)? Does the CAPTCHA display when you render the webform normally, and only fails on your custom route when you render the webform programmatically?

Comment: @sonfd nope, no JS errors. There is also nothing CAPTCHA related in the HTML source. I'm quite sure the problem is on the Drupal /backend-side. Now, I've also created a standard page which includes the webform. And no, de CAPTCHA doesn't display there either. When selecting the standard contact form instead, it works.

Comment: Are you visiting the custom form anonymous?

Comment: how did you attached the captcha to your custom form?

Comment: @Joehoe yes, see above in my question - I'm viewing it in "incognito mode". The standard  contact form works this way, the custom one not.

Comment: @AlirezaTabatabaeian I've tried both ways: 1. adding the CAPTCHA element in the form editing mode and 2. adding it via the CAPTCHA module settings by assigning it as a default to the form node type.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out there is a custom `twig` template in the theme, specifically overwriting this form only. In this template only some specific form elements are rendered:

`/web/themes/custom/some_theme/templates/webfom/webform--course-registration.html.twig`

This wasn't visible at first, because other templates related to this custom form implementation are located in the custom form module.